# Emma coverage on Enum types

Tags: java, eclipse, code-coverage, emma

I'm running EclEmma, the Emma plugin for Eclipse, and the coverage report shows only partial coverage for an Enum I've defined, even though it shows the only value in the Enum as being covered. I'm assuming that there is a coverage gap for the implied methods that back the Enum, but I'm not quite sure.

For example, with this Enum, EclEmma highlights everything in green, except for the package declaration:

```
package com.blah;

public enum UserRole {
 HAS_ACCESS
}
```

If I pull up the coverage details for the class, I see this:

[image]

My question is, what is the best way to get 100% coverage on my Enum classes using EclEmma?

Comment: My 2 cents as I have been there before and I've seen my developers falling into this trap. Feels like you are more passionate (than desired) on reaching the 100% code coverage . This is just waste of time. Coverage tool reports should just be used to identify code improvement opportunities (or reducing technical dept) and should not be seen as MUST fixes.

Comment: Does Emma not give you details about what you missed?  That seems kind of odd.

Comment: I agree, but if there is a simple way to get the coverage, I'm not going to ignore it. It is noise on a coverage report that I'd rather not have to filter through to get to real issues. I see it like not having any compiler warnings. I don't *have* to fix them all, but I don't want to filter through the less important ones to see that I have a new one that is pretty important. BTW, your answer is a non-answer and would have been better placed as a comment.

Comment: Agree...i wish i could move it to a comment now...i didn't think much if this is a comment ;-)

Comment: I agree but you can only market your code/framework/whatever with the "it has 100% test coverage" sentence if it really has it. Sad but true. +1

Answer (score 57, accepted):

What you're seeing is some hidden bytecode being generated due to an enumeration.

To get rid of this issue, add a call to the values() and valueOf() methods in the enum, as mentioned earlier by Carl Manaster and Peter Lawrey.

Comment: I found that all I needed to do was make a single call to valueOf and I get 100% coverage. I thought I'd have to do more than that.

Comment: I was facing the same issue with `enum` and `classes` . I was able to resolve with case of `enum` . But my code coverage is not covering at `package` name. any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: @Amolb your best bet is to ask a new question with all the relevant details.  This one was explicitly about `enum`s, not `package`s.

Comment: I posted this solution to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26019028/1279002

Answer (score 10):

I agree with other posters that 100% code coverage can be misguided. 
But I have to admit to the satisfaction of getting 100% coverage on newly written core code.

Fortunately since all enums extend the same 'class', you can achieve your 100% with a little help from your friend reflection.

Just add the following static method in a class for your testers to call, using [EnumTypeName].class as a parameter.

```
  public static void superficialEnumCodeCoverage(Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass) {
    try {
      for (Object o : (Object[])enumClass.getMethod("values").invoke(null)) {
        enumClass.getMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, o.toString());
      }
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

Assuming this static function was implemented in a class called "Shared", you would only need to include this line for each enum:

```
Shared.superficialEnumCodeCoverage(UserRole.class);
```

The key word is 'superficial'.

Comment: Reflection is worst kind of friend. A backstabber.

Comment: This only works if the `toString` method is not overridden in the enum class. In that case, you'll have to call `.name` instead (which makes it necessary to have `o` of an enum type (or at least of type `Enum<?>`).

Comment: if the enum does not have any fields, the coverage is still incomplete

Answer (score 2):

We ran into a similar issue where the compiler generated methods on enumerations, like values(), typically were not being called in our test code. We worked around the problem by filtering the numbers of our enum objects out of our final report.

This is why I don't like using code coverage as a measure of completeness. When I think of a better metric, I'll let you know. :)

Comment: Riffing off of this: perhaps you could write a generic test method that takes any enumeration and exercises its innate methods, just to get rid of the test report noise.  It's a little risky - if you did this with everything, you'd have 100% test coverage and no test value - but I think it might meet your needs.

Comment: You can add a generic enum exerciser which calls values() and valueOf() which you can call with exerciseEnum(MyEnum.class)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You're right about the reason for the coverage gap, but I don't think that ignoring Enums from the coverage report is the right way to go.

Comment: @Carl - You're right about the risk, it might be better to just directly test the methods for each enum, and not write a magic testing algorithm.